# Batch - Findstr - Escape chars

Tags: batch-file, variable-assignment, findstr

I have a **textfile/logfile** called *textexample.txt* with a lot of lines which was generated from a 3rd Party Software and therefore does contain a lot of special characters.

Now im searching for some special keywords in this logfile and therefore i use findstr.

The problem is that i want to store every character which has to be escaped in a variable called `charsToEscape`, but this is not working proper. Is there any 'simple' solution for my example?

**Here is the textfile "textexample.txt" im searching in**:

```
17:09:47|          |                                    |OS ver      : 1.2 AB:0.0  CD:1234 KType:-1 
17:09:48|          |InitInstance()                      |Start copy files from Section=Files 
17:09:49|          |                                    |   ******************************  
17:09:50|          |StartExe                            |Here is the Value (1234) i am searching" 
17:09:50|          |StartExe                            |your path="C:\Some\Specific\Path" 
17:09:50|          |someRandomWords                     |WaitLevel="1" (default value)
```

**Here is my Batchfile**:

```sh
@echo off
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

:MAIN
setlocal
::REM List with the expected Values im searching for..
set "expected_value_pool=9876 turn 1234 failure adios"
call :SearchValue "%expected_value_pool%" "readback_value"
if "!errorlevel!" equ "0" (
    echo readback=!readback_value!
)
pause
exit /b 0

REM Function, which checks if the give return value is in a specific textfile (line for line check)
:SearchValue
setlocal
set "_expected_value_pool=%~1"
set "_readback_value=%~2"
set "file=textexample.txt"
set "charsToEscape=/ \ > < ? | " - $ ( ) [ ] { } : = ."
set "escapeChar=^"
for /f "tokens=*" %%a in (%file%) do (
    set "act_line=%%a"
    for %%c in (%charsToEscape%) do (
        set "act_line=!act_line:%%c=%escapeChar%%%c!"
    )
    for %%i in (%_expected_value_pool%) do (
        echo !act_line!|findstr /r "^.*%%i.*$" >NUL
        if "!errorlevel!" equ "0" (
            (endlocal
                if "%_readback_value%" neq "" (set "%_readback_value%=%%i")
            )
        exit /b 0
        )
    )
)
exit /b 1
```

**UPDATE**:

i get the error `">" cant be processed syntactically at this point` from the line `set "charsToEscape=/ \ > < ? | " - $ ( ) [ ] { } : = ."` due to the special characters which cannot be proper processed

Comment: Although your explanation is very clear, I am afraid I don't understand what exactly is your problem...  I copy-pasted your file and tested this command: `findstr "9876 turn 1234 failure adios" textexample.txt` and get as result the two lines that contain `CD:1234` and `(1234)`.  Whats next?

Comment: You may have some specific difficulty with the `=` character if you're performing a variable expansion and substitution, and as you've enabled delayed expansion from the very start, issues with `!` characters. Other than that, I'm not sure what your specific and reproducible issue is! Perhaps you should at the very least tell us which real world input arguments are causing you problems.

Comment: Sorry for confusion: I postet an update for my specific failure in this Thread

Comment: If your looking for a simpler way, perhaps you should tell us what you want to achieve instead of having us each individually work out from your code what it is. Just "do any of these strings appear in the source text?" or is there something else? `cmd` only, or are tou open to using public-domain utilities like `sed` and `(g)awk`?

Comment: Hm… I'd try to replace `echo !act_line!| findstr …` by `cmd /D /V /C echo(^!act_line^!| findstr …`; that way you force the variable `act_line` to become delayedly expanded in the "inner" `cmd.exe` rather than the main one, so poisonous characters are not exposed to the "inner" instance in an unescaped manner…